# Trying to relaod api inside command but getting some errors in debug

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
@client.command() 
async def eth(ctx):
  while True:
    r = requests.request("GET", eth_api, headers=headers)
    data2 = r.json()
    eth_price = data2['data']['rates']['USD']
    await ctx.message.delete()
    await ctx.send(f"The price of ETH is {eth_price}$")
    sleep(0.2)
```

```
Ignoring exception in command eth:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/Elon-Musk/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 35, in eth
    await ctx.message.delete()
  File "/home/runner/Elon-Musk/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/message.py", line 1023, in delete
    await self._state.http.delete_message(self.channel.id, self.id)
  File "/home/runner/Elon-Musk/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 250, in request
    raise NotFound(r, data)
discord.errors.NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10008): Unknown Message

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/Elon-Musk/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/runner/Elon-Musk/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/home/runner/Elon-Musk/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10008): Unknown Message
```

I am getting this error in debug whenever i use the command but the command is working fine, i think it's because it's trying to delete in a loop that's why, any better way to refresh API's and do it?

Comment: I can't tell what error you're getting as you didn't post the entire traceback, but you can use try/except to handle the error. Also, you might want to [edit] your question to add the "discord" and/or "discord.py" tags.

Comment: edited @NathanMills

Comment: it seems unable to get the request r

Comment: @A5taroth when i remove the loop it works so idk why it can't find

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is the `await ctx.message.delete()` line - during the first iteration of the `while` loop, the original command message will be deleted. This means that it won't be available any longer, and from the second iteration on, trying to delete it again will cause the error you're seeing because the message no longer exists. You can fix this by simply moving the `await ctx.message.delete()` line outside of the `while` loop